# How did the Millennium Falcon appear in Blade Runner?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon, blade-runner, props, blade-runner-series

What is the story behind that the fact that the Millennium Falcon actually is in the set of Blade Runner? The producers must've known that the audience would recognize and debate it, and such a thing is rarely done when some stuff from one movie appears in another like that.

**What is the special history about how the prop for the Falcon was included in Blade Runner?**

Comment: You'd be surprised at how many times props are reused between movies, or how many cheats are taken - especially in large, model-heavy shots. For example, the [potato and tennis shoe in ESB and RotJ](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7925/where-is-the-shoe-in-the-space-battle-in-return-of-the-jedi), or if you really want to lose some time, check out the [prop recycling trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PropRecycling)

Comment: @Niklasrtz: Screen capture?

Comment: Just to add to the cityscape list: the Dark Star ship and a toilet bowl IIRC.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> "Bill George had been making a replica of the Millennium Falcon, Han Solo's ship from the Star Wars movies, for his own amusement," Stetson explained. "It was about five feet tall. At the time we were so frantic to get more buildings into the cityscape that we grabbed Bill's ship, bristled it with etched brass, and plopped it into different shots. Instant building.

Further details [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20070708222034/http://www.brmovie.com/Locations/Falcon.htm).